# Fragments disappears after adding ButtonBar to the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, buttonbar

I am trying to create a master detail UI with three fragments and two buttons button bar. For some reason, the fragments are not showing up in the UI after adding the button bar. I suspect it has something to do with the orientation of the layout but I'll leave it up to the experts here.

[Before adding the button bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EWBN.png)

[After adding the button bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNgkz.png)

Here is the XML layout of the UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainBodyFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.MainBodyArea" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/subBodyFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.SubBodyArea" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/symptomFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.Symptom" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Generate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
        android:text="@string/generate" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#909090" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ViewList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
        android:text="@string/viewlist" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#F0F0F0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Generate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
            android:text="@string/generate" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#909090" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_ViewList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
            android:text="@string/viewlist" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainBodyFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.MainBodyArea" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/subBodyFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.SubBodyArea" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/symptomFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.Symptom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

your first `LinearLayout` has the orientation horizontal (so everything will be next to the others), than you add your button bar with the `width="match_parent"`, so the button bar uses the hold vertical space. If you want to put the fragments below eachothers change the `orientation` of the first to vertical. If the fragments shall be next to each other and the button bar below use the following code: (the first `LinearLayout` is not closed in your code!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainBodyFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.MainBodyArea" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/subBodyFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.SubBodyArea" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/symptomFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    class="com.dreamcode.healttracker.Symptom" />
</LinearLayout> <!-- added -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Generate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
    android:text="@string/generate" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#909090" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_ViewList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/borderless_button"
    android:text="@string/viewlist" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out the closing tag (edited. Missed the indentation by 4 spaces). I have tried your code and it is not what I am trying to achieve. I want the fragments to show side by side and the button bar at the bottom. I have updated the question with images (in links) so that you can see what I am trying to achieve here

Comment: Sorry I missed a closing tag, too, check again, please